# Running all tests in project using different working directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I need run all tests from my multimodule project using IDE. Like I do it using maven. I can run it by running all tests from specific package. But I need corresponding working directory (`$MODULE_DIR$`) for tests from each module. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set working directory to `$MODULE_DIR$` in the template (Default) run configuration that you are using. All the new configurations of this type will inherit this default setting.

Comment: Yes. I've already done it. There is other issue. I want to run all my tests at once. But tests shouldn't share working directory. Each test should use directory from it's own module.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible, vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66345.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it will be implemented soon)